# Drop 0s in date charcaters

Tags: r, regex, date

I'm looking for a way to drop (if they exist) 0s in `day and month` representation of the date. Also, I have the format of the character...

Here is a reproducible example of what i want:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    exemple = c(
      "01/12/2017",
      "01-02-2017",
      "2017/02/12",
      "2017/02/01",
      "2017/02/01 10:01:05",
      "2017/02/01 02:01:05"
    ),
    format  = c(
      "%d/%m/%Y"  ,
      "%d-%m-%Y"  ,
      "%Y/%d/%m"  ,
      "%Y/%d/%m"  ,
      "%Y/%d/%m %H:%m:%s"  ,
      "%Y/%d/%m %H:%m:%s"
    ),
    result  = c(
      "1/12/2017",
      "1-2-2017"  ,
      "2017/2/12" ,
      "2017/2/1"  ,
      "2017/2/1 10:01:05"  ,
      "2017/2/1 02:01:05"
    )
  )
```

Which give:

```
              exemple            format            result
1          01/12/2017          %d/%m/%Y         1/12/2017
2          01-02-2017          %d-%m-%Y          1-2-2017
3          2017/02/12          %Y/%d/%m         2017/2/12
4          2017/02/01          %Y/%d/%m          2017/2/1
5 2017/02/01 10:01:05 %Y/%d/%m %H:%m:%s 2017/2/1 10:01:05
6 2017/02/01 02:01:05 %Y/%d/%m %H:%m:%s 2017/2/1 02:01:05
```

It contains the following columns:

- example: the date I have
- format: the format of each date
- result: what i want.

As you can see, each date has a different format so I'm looking to the most generic way to do it.
**By most generic, i mean that it should work with any type of seperator, and any date format**

### Edit:

Please note that I'm note confusing content of a variable with a formated output: I want to transform the character it self.

Thanks.

Comment: You are confusing _content_ of a variable with a _formated output_.  What you want here is simply a custom conversion of character.  The underlying value never changes.

Comment: I don't think so... My variables exemple and format are both character. I want to delete the 0 in exemple column.

Comment: That's "worse" because you can't do anything with characters.  At some point you want them parsed.  And, sorry to break that to you, removing the zeros makes that harder.  Also, in a `data.frame` in particular, you can keep both the `Date` (ie parsed) and whatever pretty-printed version you want.

Comment: I want to do that for a specific usage. And don't worry, even if 0s are dropped, given the format R will stille be able to parse them.

Comment: Looks to me like three quick `gsub`s: replace `"/0"` with `"/"`, `"-0"` with `"-"`,  and `"^0"` with `""`. This will fail if you have any cases where the time comes at the start of the string as you want to keep 0s in the time part, but that could be worked around by looking at your format column.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor, indeed in this case 3 gsub would work, but I want the most generic way to do it: meaning with any type of separator (/, -, :, ... )

Comment: Okay, what have you tried and where are you stuck? Seems like you are requiring that you pull the separators before `%Y%` `%d` and `%m` out of your format string. Have you attempted that?

Comment: `x = "01/12/2017"; fmt = "%d/%m/%Y"; format(d <- strptime(x, fmt), gsub("%d", gsub("0(.)", "\\1", format(d, "%d")), fmt))` and similarly insert format+gsubs for each other thing you want to change -- I agree that this is a bad / not useful thing to do, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
df$myresult = gsub("(?<=^|(?![:])[[:punct:]])0", "", df$exemple, perl = TRUE)
```

**Result:**

```
> df
              exemple            format            result          myresult
1          01/12/2017          %d/%m/%Y         1/12/2017         1/12/2017
2          01-02-2017          %d-%m-%Y          1-2-2017          1-2-2017
3          2017/02/12          %Y/%d/%m         2017/2/12         2017/2/12
4          2017/02/01          %Y/%d/%m          2017/2/1          2017/2/1
5 2017/02/01 10:01:05 %Y/%d/%m %H:%m:%s 2017/2/1 10:01:05 2017/2/1 10:01:05
6 2017/02/01 02:01:05 %Y/%d/%m %H:%m:%s 2017/2/1 02:01:05 2017/2/1 02:01:05
```

**Note:**

This regex looks a bit weird because I am placing a negative lookahead inside a positive lookbehind. `(?![:])[[:punct:]]` matches all punctuation marks *except* `:`. So the entire regex matches **all 0's that either come after a punctuation mark not including `:`, or is at the beginning of the string**.

Answer (score 0):

This will identify the date by looking for a string containing a four-digit year, and then use `gsub` to remove any zeros that are not preceded by another digit.  So it should leave years, times and non-leading zeros alone.  The `x` in the function is the capture group from the first argument (i.e. the date).

This should even work if you have `:` as a date separator, or something other than `:` (such as `-`) as a time separator, but it will fail if you have two-digit years.

```
library(gsubfn)
df$result <- gsubfn("([^\\s]*\\d{4}[^\\s]*)",
                    ~gsub("(^|[^0-9]+)0(\\d+)", "\\1\\2", x),
                    as.character(df$exemple))

df
              exemple            format            result
1          01/12/2017          %d/%m/%Y         1/12/2017
2          01-02-2017          %d-%m-%Y          1-2-2017
3          2017/02/12          %Y/%d/%m         2017/2/12
4          2017/02/01          %Y/%d/%m          2017/2/1
5 2017/02/01 10:01:05 %Y/%d/%m %H:%m:%s 2017/2/1 10:01:05
6 2017/02/01 02:01:05 %Y/%d/%m %H:%m:%s 2017/2/1 02:01:05
```

Comment: `:` as date separators is rare, but two-digit years are very common.